# Need help to convert the below SQL query to MySQL without cross apply method

Tags: mysql, sql, cross-apply

Need to extract the below query on MySQL -

```
select ut.ID, aa.Name, ut.Parent, aa.Geneology,
convert(int,(len(aa.Geneology)-len(Replace(aa.Geneology,',','')))-1) 'Level'
from (select u.id, x.Name, x.Geneology
      from userDT u cross apply
           (select n.Geneology,n.Name
            from userDT n
            Where n.Geneology like '%' + u.Geneology + '%'
           ) x
      where u.id=3
     ) aa left join
     userDT ut
     on ut.Geneology = aa.Geneology";
```

UserDT Table -

```
id  Name    Parent  Geneology
1   abc -   1,
2   def abc 1,2
3   ghi abc 1,3
4   jkl def 1,2,4
5   mno ghi 1,3,5
6   pqr def 1,2,6
7   stu ghi 1,3,7
8   vwx mno 1,3,5,8
9   xyz vwx 1,3,5,8,9
```

Result should be like this -

```
ID  Name    Parent  Geneology   Level
3   ghi abc 1,3         0
5   mno ghi 1,3,5           1
7   stu ghi 1,3,7           1
8   vwx mno 1,3,5,8         2
9   xyz vwx 1,3,5,8,9   3
```

Comment: `Where n.Geneology like '%' + u.Geneology + '%'` this is dangerous. Let `u.Geneology` =2 and `n.Geneology` = '4,12' , producing false positive.

Comment: You are right, i will re-write the query accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just convert that to a `join`.  In MySQL syntax, I think the query would look like:

```
select ut.ID, aa.Name, ut.Parent, aa.Geneology,
       (len(aa.Geneology)-len(Replace(aa.Geneology, ',', '')))-1 as Level
from (select u.id, x.Name, x.Geneology
      from userDT u join
           userDT x
           on x.Geneology like concat('%', u.Geneology, '%')       ) x
      where u.id = 3
     ) aa left join
     userDT ut
     on ut.Geneology = aa.Geneology;
```

Frankly, I don't see it doing much useful in either MySQL or SQL Server.  You might want to ask another question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.